# POST request to localhost using Python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-requests

I have my Django website running on my local server at port 8000. From a separate python file, I want to send a post request triggering one endpoint of my website.

But unable to do that even after adding all the required info. Please help!!

```
import requests
URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/org/create/'
client = requests.Session()
client.get(URL)
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']

data = dict(csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken)
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
response = client.post(URL, data=data,cookies=client.cookies, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

It is giving me this error.

```
EC:\Program Files\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py:643: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=420, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 10510), raddr=('127.0.0
.1', 8000)>
  outcome.errors.clear()

======================================================================
ERROR: test_org_create (test_org.TestOrg)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\test_org.py", line 13, in test_org_create
    csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 328, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 399, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"
```

How to resolve this?
**Please comment for any other info.**

Comment: Why do you want to use `requests` module here?

Comment: What else I can use? I'm actually writing unit test for my Rest API and writing the tests in the stand-alone test file.Any other idea?

Comment: What about [Django test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#default-test-client) ?

Comment: Actually, I cannot use that since it requires dependencies like database engine and I'm using Dynamo DB externally. That's why I have written a separate test file to test my website. Many people faced the same issue. How can send a post request to my local server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking at the error and the [requests docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/requests/cookies/) from the following section:

```py
def _find_no_duplicates(self, name, domain=None, path=None):
        """Both ``__get_item__`` and ``get`` call this function: it's never
        used elsewhere in Requests.

       ... blah blah ignore this, alot of stuff

        :raises KeyError: if cookie is not found
     
       ... blah blah also ignore this, another lot of stuff
```

Seeing `:raises KeyError: if cookie is not found` seems like you are missing the cookie. Have you checked if it is correctly set in the response as you intended?

Comment: Although I have added cookies but will check if they are as per requirement.